# JavaFX8 seamless in jdk 1.7.85?

Tags: java, swing, javafx, javafx-8

I am developing a new desktop application . The target machines are having jdk 1.7.85 and 1.7.51. Is it advisable to create the desktop app in JavaFX 8 and then bundle it as an EXE and run it on the target machines. JavaFX 8 has most of the latest updates i feel. If this will create some problem then I have to go with traditional SWING. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaFX features are utilized best with jdk 1.8 or higher. So I am going with Swing as it is feasible for me right now compared to JavaFX.